# Can I search a sorted List<T> faster when it is sorted on the fields I search on?

Tags: c#, sorting, find, binary-search

I thougt that sorting a `List<T>` on the fields I search on would make the search faster.
Suppose I have a `List<Person>` of 10.000 and a `List<Car>` of 10.000 in an object Model.
I loop the Persons list in the Model and want to find the Car with the property c.Owner == person.Name.

```
public static Car Car(Model model, Person person)
        {
            return model.Cars.Find(
                 delegate(Car c)
                 {
                     return c.Owner.Equals(person.Name);
                 });
        }
```

Sorting the list of cars on property owner doesn't make the loop faster?

I thought maybe I should use `BinarySearch` but the overloads of `BinarySearch` do not permit delegates. What is überhaupt the use of `BinarySearch` when you have to give the Car you want to lookup as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) doesn't accept a delegate, but it *does* have [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx) that accepts an `IComparer<T>`. Use that overload with the appropriate custom comparer (`CarByOwnerComparer : IComparer<Car>`) to get it to search the way you want it to. Of course, bear in mind that the list has to be *already* sorted with that comparer to allow binary-search to work. If you prefer writing a delegate (e.g. through a lambda) to implementing an interface, consider using a converter that can translate between the two, such as the [`ProjectionComparer`](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/ProjectionComparer.cs?spec=svn0c583631b709679831c99df2646fc9adb781b2be&r=0c583631b709679831c99df2646fc9adb781b2be) provided here.

However, I would suggest that you  use a more appropriate collection-class instead, which provides fast retrieval by key. For example,  `SortedList<,>` and `SortedDictionary<,>` will both do the job in  `O(logn)`. If ordering is not a true requirement, it might be a lot easier to just go with `Dictionary<,>`.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your answer. I used IComparer<Car> but to discover I cannot use delegates in BinarySearch. So I don't understand how writing the interface IComparer<Car> (I suppose that's the interface you mean) helps. I will have to do lookups on different combination of fields, so I considered to do different sort's prior to looping and lookups in the loop.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer. I considered SortedDictionary but I will have to be able to use different sets of keys - I don't suppose it is possible or sensibe to change all keys? Or could I make the key a facade that has different values depending on some setting?

Comment: @Gerard: I'm finding it hard to understand that, and anyway I doubt that could be answered with a simple comment. (The best I can say is: yes, you can write a class that encapsulates multiple properties and use that as a key). May I suggest you ask a different question that clarifies these issues? Cheers.

Comment: I see now that it is a good answer. I will follow up with another question and try out some of these ideas.